# Read the first number of the field

Tags: formula, fields

I need help please on the formula field i want to have value a VISA or MC. I have to read the first number of specific field.

For example, the account is 465xxxx868. The account is starting by 4 then it should be VISA. If 5 then it should be MC.

Any tips are most welcome to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried LEFT(fieldName, 1)?

Comment: thanks matt but how will i return the value of my new formula field that it's "VISA" or "MC"

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5) and also the [Trailhead tutorials](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula expression in your formula field.

```
IF( 
  BEGINS(Name, '4'), 'VISA', 
  IF( 
     BEGINS(Name, '5'), 'MC', ''
  )
)
```